# Setting A Field to Entity in Symfony Form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

In my project, I have two entities. Post and Comment.

`Comment` entity has following fields

- name
- message
- post

I'm rendering comment form just after post. Presently in comment form I'm getting a drop down menu from which I can select a post. I don't that. I want to set post field to a default value which is same as the post rendered above that. And it should not be changeable.

How can I achieve this behavior?

**UPDATE**

I have following code in my controller
    $comment = new Comment();

```
$comment -> setPost($entity);
$commentForm = $this -> createCommentForm($comment);
return array(
  'entity'      => $entity,
  'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
  'comment_form' => $commentForm->createView()
);
```

In this code, I'm setting post value, which is coming as default value in form, but it is changeable.

I'm creating form using following code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('reference')
    ->add('post','entity', array(
       'class' => 'OpenSourceFeedBundle:Post',
       'required' => TRUE
     ))
    ->add('date', 'date', array(
      'html5' => TRUE,
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'read_only' => TRUE
    ))
    ->add('message')
    ;
  }
```

Comment: How it is actually changeable? I dont see a field in your comment form that handles that dropdown for post. So in this case, you should not see any dropdown in comment form, which means you can't change it.

Comment: @MichalTakáč. Oh sorry. I had a field there. Just removed that for experimental purpose. Please check now.

Comment: So, all you need is remove that field I guess and you should be fine right? you will not be able to change the post in comment form and you will have your post set to the comment, right? :)

Comment: @MichalTakáč. If I remove that, field, then `post` is not getting submitted with `comment` and it showing exception.

Comment: Can you share the exception?

Comment: @MichalTakáč, After submission, I'm trying to redirect to `view post` page using post id. When I'm accessing post id, from post in comment object, I'm getting `call to member function on null` error. Also, comment is added to table, with null value for post.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up comment $post value in controller. Can you show me your post/show action of your Post controller?

Basically you have show action of the post, in your controller you have post object available, so when post trigger you should do something like this

```
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setPost($post);
```

and then do what ever you need to do, like flush comment to the database.

In twig you should not display that part with dropdown.

If you will be able to paste twig and controller I will show you solution.

Comment: I have updated question. Please have a look. I have already tried setting values for post as you told. It is setting given post as default value. But still it is changeable.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#disabled)

> disabled
>
> type: boolean default: false
>
> If you don't want a user to modify the value of a field, you can set
>   the disabled option to true. Any submitted value will be ignored.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
  {
    $builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('reference')
    ->add('post','entity', array(
       'class' => 'OpenSourceFeedBundle:Post',
       'required' => TRUE,
       'disabled' => true,
     ))
    ->add('date', 'date', array(
      'html5' => TRUE,
      'widget' => 'single_text',
      'read_only' => TRUE
    ))
    ->add('message')
    ;
  }
```

Comment: In html form if we make some field disabled, it won't be submitted with form. In this case I won't be having any value for post, when I submit form.